# View, what View?

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, view

Looking for advice on the best View layout to use and avoid future re-work.  The requirement is to display an image and a few lines of descriptive text (say, < 5 lines) in the middle of the screen.  The image plus text will be of approximate size 1.5 inch square.

A future version will require that the image+text combo can be swiped left/right and up/down.

A menu of buttons will be provided but don't need help with that.  I'm looking for advice on the best View layout to start with (not help with the code).  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LinearLayout` sounds pretty appetizing to me...

Comment: Okay, I see how that would work.  Using flickr images as the example data, navigation is primarily left/right through buttons or swipe.  To avoid going to the server to get a new image+text combo each time, it might be a good idea to cache a small number on the device.  If so, what is best option - a gallery view structure or just keep cached images in local db or something else?